# Expected a method with IAsyncResult BeginSend

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, task-parallel-library, asyncsocket

Hi I'm trying to create a TAP wrapper. The ConnectTaskAsync is fine, however I'm having some difficulties with SendTaskAsync.

```
public static Task ConnectTaskAsync(this Socket socket, EndPoint endpoint)
        {
            return Task.Factory.FromAsync(socket.BeginConnect, socket.EndConnect, endpoint, null);
        }

    public static Task<int> SendTaskAsync(this Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, SocketFlags flags)
    {
        return Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(socket.BeginSend, buffer, offset, size, flags, socket.EndSend, null);
    }
```

The error I'm getting is a red underline beneath `BeginSend` with the message Expected a method with IAsyncResult BeginSend

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `FromAsync` defined incorrectly.  Unfortunately, there isn't an [overload of FromAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync.aspx) which accepts 4 separate arguments (which would be required for `BeginSend`), so you'll need to [use a different overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321429.aspx):

```
public static Task<int> SendTaskAsync(this Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, SocketFlags flags)
{
    AsyncCallback nullOp = (i) => {};
    IAsyncResult result = socket.BeginSend(buffer, offset, size, flags, nullOp, socket);
    // Use overload that takes an IAsyncResult directly
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync(result, socket.EndSend);
}
```

Comment: Isn't callback allowed to be `null`?

Comment: @svick I'm not actually 100% sure - there's nothing in the documentation specifying that it's optional (I think it's implementation dependent), and I'm not sure if `Socket.BeginSend` expects it to exist...

Comment: There's an error on socket.EndSend "Cannot choose method from method group. Did you intend to invoke that method?"

Comment: @The8thBit Odd - you should be able to write it as either: `return Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(result, socket.EndSend);` or `return Task.Factory.FromAsync(result, (i) => socket.EndSend(i));`  Compiler may need a bit of extra help here